# How can I sort the values of variables of multivariate polynomial f by increasing order of value of f

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, multivariate-polynomial

Assume that I have a multivariate polynomial over positive integers, the coefficients $a_i$ are all 1, e.g . $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_3^4+x_2+x_1^2x_2x_4^5$, each monomial and each $x_i > 0$.

I have two questions, if you will.

1. How can I sort the values of tuples of the variables in increasing order of $f$ values? For the example above, the minimum equivalence class is $f(..x_i..) = 3$, with tuples such as $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (1,1,1,1). Is there a way of doing it not in a brute force of solving for each value? Hopefully there is a way of doing so just by looking at the polynomial itself. Is it a matter of sorting according to the degree?
2. Closely related, assume that I have an upper bound on the value of $f$. e.g. $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) < 500$. can I immediately calculate the possible upper integer bounds on each of the variables? I understand that each of the $x_i$ is lower than the upper bound, but are there better results for each variable? calculating all combinations would be prohibitive. I can see some similarity to the knapsack problem.

I am not a mathematician, the questions are related to a polynomial representation of data structures I have in a software project, I try to calculate the feasible solutions in the most efficient manner. I hope the problems/solutions are quite known to you already :)

Many thanks,
Joseph

Comment: Not clear that there will be upper bounds on the variables. In your example, if $x_2=0$, then $x_1$ and $x_4$ can be arbitrarily large. This also rules out ordering the variables by the value of the function.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, you are absolutely right. Following your comment, I modified the question to exclude such cases (i.e, ruling out $x_i = 0$, and not allowing monomials to be 0). Does it help now?

Comment: OK. Now, in your example, you have $x_1\le22$, $x_2\le249$, $x_3\le4$, and $x_4\le3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson.  I see.. we sum the appearances of the highest degree of $x_i$ and solve for the upper bound for each $x_i$ separately ?

Regarding the sort, that would still force me to sort the space of variables assignments (up to $x_1≤22, x_2≤249, x_3≤4, x_4≤3)$ by the value of $f$, right? Can we do better than computing the polynomial and sorting each possible assignment?

Thank you :)

Comment: I don't know. Probably not much better.